# How to use gradient accumulation with a loss function requires the entire batch

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I’m using gradient accumulation in my code to address memory limitations with large batch sizes. The choice of my loss function depends on the overall probability values across the entire batch. However, I can’t be sure if the probs_avg is still computed for the accumulated batch, not the minibatch? Here’s my current code:

```
#----------------------- for grad accumulation ----------------------
global_step = 0 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
for step, (x, y, idx) in enumerate(metric_logger.log_every(data_loader_u, print_freq, header)):
    x = x.to(device, non_blocking=True)
    y = y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
        logit = model(x)
        probs_all = F.softmax(logits,dim=-1) 
        probs_batch_avg = probs_all.mean(0) # average prediction 
        # moving average          
        if global_step==0:
            probs_avg = probs_batch_avg
        else:    
            probs_avg = 0.5*(probs_avg.detach()+probs_batch_avg)
        loss_x = -(torch.log(probs_avg)).mean() / 0.5
        #----------------------------------------------------------
        loss = (loss_x) / accumulation_steps
    ## ---------------------- for grad accumulation --------------
    loss.backward()
    if (data_iter_step + 1) % accumulation_steps == 0:
        global_step+=1
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

I need to know how to implement gradient accumulation with a loss function that requires the whole batch?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish here? Your loss function doesn't make sense. You softmax, but don't select specific classes for the loss. You have a `y` variable but it is not used in the loss. You scale probabilities by the last batch average prob, but this is detached and won't meaningfully influence the loss. Your loss `loss_x = -(torch.log(probs_avg)).mean()` just tells the model to "make all probabilities large", which isn't possible due to how softmax works.

Comment: The loss function is a fairness regularization to mitigate confirmation bias. I took this loss function from here: [https://github.com/salesforce/MUST/blob/1e0f84eb77ed0a3e57f3c14e67e987bccf5212c7/engine_self_training.py#L69](https://github.com/salesforce/MUST/blob/1e0f84eb77ed0a3e57f3c14e67e987bccf5212c7/engine_self_training.py#L69). I am interested in adjusting this loss function for gradient accumulation, since I can't afford multiple GPUs.